# Uniform convergence of Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am currently studying Fourier Analysis on my own. In the Notes I use the following comment is made, which I unfortunately don't understand:

Given that we know the series

$f(x) = \sum c_k e^{ikx}$

converges pointwise (where the $c_k$ are the Fourier coefficients and $f$ is a periodic function), to show uniform convergence it is enough to show that

$
\sum |c_k| < \infty
$

I tried to find the result regarding uniform convergence that this comment refers to but so far I wasn't successful.

Could somebody help me and give a hint as to why this is true ? Many thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: exactly does the job, many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is just an application of the [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

It's a rather simple result, and it is edifying to prove the uniform convergence of your series  directly:

Let $m> n$, then
$$
\biggl| \sum_{j=1}^m c_j e^{ijx}  - \sum_{j=1}^n c_j e^{ijx} \biggr|
=\biggl| \sum_{j=n+1}^m c_j e^{ijx}   \biggr|
\le \sum_{j=n+1}^m |c_j e^{ijx} |=  \sum_{j=n+1}^m |c_j   |.
$$
Since $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty |c_j|<\infty$, we can make the right hand side of the above as small as we wish provided $n$ is sufficiently large. Thus, we can make the left hand side as small as we wish, independently of  $x$, as long as $n$ is sufficiently large.

It follows that $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty c_j e^{ijx} $ is uniformly Cauchy, and, thus, uniformly convergent.

Comment: Perhaps you should say something regarding the lower index, since complex Fourier series starts from $i=-\infty$.

Comment: But $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty |c_j|<\infty$ is not a given, though, is it?

Comment: @Ryker I interpreted the OP's question as "why would assuming $\sum|c_j|<\infty$ imply $f(x)$ is uniformly convergent?"

Comment: @DavidMitra, I see. Yeah, taking another look at it I think you're right.

Comment: Isn't the last equality actually an inequality? I believe you were adapting the proof itself of the Weierstrass M-Test for this sequence of functions specifically.