# Uniformly convergence of the Fourier Series with coefficients in $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

How can I prove these statements?

> For each sequence of coefficients $c=\{c_k\} \in\ell^1$, the Fourier series $S_c=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}c_ke^{ikt}$ converges uniformly to a continuous function. Furthermore, the operator $\ell^1 \longrightarrow C^0([-\pi,\pi])$ defined by $c \mapsto S_c$ is continuous.

I thought about Banach-Steinhaus theorem and the continuity of a limited function between normed spaces but I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Your statement is missing something.  What about p?

Comment: Do you know that the functions $t\mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{ikt}$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$ are an orthonormal system in the Hilbert space $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ with scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\overline g(t)\,dt$? Then try finding an upper bound for the $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm of the sum and show absolute convergence.

Comment: No that's all, I don't know why in the notes $p$ is mentioned.

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102827/234623 (So you don't need $L^2$-spaces at all, actually)

Comment: Oops, the answer there is missing the continuity part, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e_k\in C[-\pi,\pi]$ be defined by $e_k(t) := e^{ikt}$, then the sum of continuous functions converges absolutely in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm because

$\sum_k \|c_k e_k\|_\infty = \sum_k |c_k|\cdot\|e_k\|_\infty
= \sum_k |c_k| = \|c\|_1 < \infty$

This implies uniform convergence $\sum_k c_k e_k = S_c$ for some continuous $S_c\in C[-\pi,\pi]$. The map $c\mapsto S_c$ is continuous because it is linear and the above computation shows

$\|S_c\|_\infty\le\sum_k \|c_k e_k\|_\infty\le\|c\|_1$

Therefore the map has operator norm 1 and thus is continuous.